# Do I need a transit visa in Zurich on the way to Vietnam?

Tags: visas, transit, zurich, vietnamese-citizens

I am Vietnamese and I am flying from Dusseldorf to Vietnam, and I will take the transit in Zurich within 15 hours. I want to go to the Zurich center. Any transit visa or any special documents I should have? I don't have any Schengen visa.

Comment: How did you get _into_ the Schengen area without a visa, then?

Comment: On what basis are you staying in Düsseldorf? A residence permit?

Answer (score 3):

If you embark in Düsseldorf, it means you are already in the Schengen area (and since you don't have a short stay visa, you presumably have some other legal title to be there like a German residence permit). You won't leave the area before Zurich.

In most cases, you won't see any border guard before you go to the non-Schengen part of Zurich airport and you will in any case be free to leave the airport and do whatever you want. It's only when you go to catch your Vietnam-bound plane that you will be stamped out.

If you are coming from somewhere else, say London-Düsseldorf-Zurich-Vietnam, then you definitely need a Schengen visa for this transit, not merely to see the city in Zurich but also to be allowed to board your plane and catch the Düsseldorf-Zurich leg.

Either way, if you are able to follow this itinerary, you won't have any problem leaving the airport in Zurich.